# Calling on apps like whatsapp viber works on which protocol?

Tags: android, wifi

Does the calling on apps like whatsapp, viber works on VoIP protocol or some other because I am thinking of making an app which could connect devices connected to same wifi and make calls to each other?

Answer (score 1):

Viber and WhatsApp have some kind of VoIP implementation. But since this is closed source software, we don't know the exact implementation details.
You could implement your own or an open source VoIP library, but the minimal you need is a server/client and/or p2p setup and you'll also need an audio codec that works over low bandwidth connections.
 This is a rather advanced project.
To discover devices in your network, you could use UDP for broadcasting.

Answer (score 0):

For such app you can try to use standart Android SIP API

[Session Initiation Protocol](http://Session%20Initiation%20Protocol)

Comment: Don't we require an internet connection for this? I am looking for something which I can use to make connection over wifi without any internet requirement.

Answer (score 0):

[WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/) is a pretty interesting framework that achieves these goals. Here's a pretty interesting [article](https://tech.appear.in/2015/05/25/Introduction-to-WebRTC-on-Android/) about using WebRTC on Android, worth having a look.